# Podcasts in colloquial German

Tags: colloquial, resource, big-list

I’ve been trying for some time to find podcasts in colloquial language. That is, I’m *not* looking for podcasts with news and interviews or for language-learning podcasts. Specifically, I’m looking for podcasts that are discussions among 2–5 people.

I tried to look on iTunes, but couldn’t find anything. Online searches yielded mostly newsy-podcasts. Any recommendations?

Comment: If you have some interest in computer related stuff, this might be for you: http://freakshow.fm/

Comment: colloquial speech depends on the geographic region. People in Cologne speak different than people from Dresden, same for Hamburg, Vienna, or Zurich.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with Carsten Schultz about Küchenradio.

While [Freak Show](http://freakshow.fm/) by [Metaebene](http://metaebene.me/) looks like a tech podcast with up to 5 people discussing news at first, it's not a typical interview podcast and it's also not just a collection of news bits. They tend to digress a lot resulting in long episodes. If tech and length don't turn you off, you might want to give this a try.

Holger Klein's [Realitätsabgleich](http://www.wrint.de/category/realitaetsabgleich/) and [Wrintheit](http://www.wrint.de/category/wrintheit/) are discussions between 2 people for about 1 to 2 hours and published along with his other podcasts on [wrint.de](http://wrint.de/).

Previously Tim from Metaebene and Holgi published a podcast called [Not Safe For Work](http://not-safe-for-work.de/) that might also be what you are looking for and be worth listening to despite the provocative title. In some episodes they talk about [videos from Kurt Razelli](https://www.google.de/search?q=not-safe-for-work.de%20kurt%20razelli) featuring austrian dialect where Tim expresses his admiration for this dialect.

[Alternativlos](http://alternativlos.org/) is a podcast by Frank Rieger and [Felix von Leitner](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_von_Leitner) 
focused more on politics and history than on tech. At the time of writing the [latest episode](http://alternativlos.org/33/) featured [Sascha Lobo](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sascha_Lobo) as a guest. Note while there is usually an interesting discussion between the two and available guests, the format may be changed to an interview style as in [episode 24](http://blog.fefe.de/?ts=b10f19d7) with [Mathias Döpfner](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathias_D%C3%B6pfner). The podcast doesn't have a regular schedule.

---

- [Schall und Rauch](http://schallrauch.hoersuppe.de/sur/show)

  > [Alexander](http://www.hoaxilla.com/team/hoaxmaster/) und Christian, zwei mittelreife Früchte der 70er, sozialisiert in den 80ern veröffentlichen ihre monatlichen Schwätzchen auf der Parkbank.

Comment: Good suggestions... I imagine Holger Klein to be a bit of a challenge for students because his way of speaking is a bit "hectic". Also, their German is rife with Anglicisms, to a degree which is beyond normal. But in the tech-scene it is.

Answer (score 6):

There's also [Teezeit](http://www.teezeit.org/), a podcast about everything from TV shows to Computers.

edit:
@LiveWireBT's answer reminded me of [Chaosradio](http://chaosradio.ccc.de/) and [Chaosradio Express](http://cre.fm/archiv) a.k.a. CRE, which I highly recommend.

Answer (score 5):

Das [Küchenradio](http://www.kuechenstud.io/kuechenradio/), insbesondere ältere Ausgaben, könnte dem entsprechen, selbst wenn es von Journalisten gemacht wird.

Answer (score 3):

A good recommendation for discussions in Germany would first of all be all of the German TV talk shows, which usually get posted online. Not sure if that was what you were looking for. This for example is [`Anne Will`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/das-erste-anne-will/id277698119?mt=2). [`Hart aber Fair`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/hart-aber-fair/id170841476?mt=2), or [`WDR 5 Presseclub`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/wdr-5-presseclub/id164775707?mt=2) would work too.

If you want pure podcasts you could look at [`Logbuch:Netzpolitik`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/logbuch-netzpolitik/id476856034?mt=2), or [`Lage der Nation`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/lage-der-nation-der-politik-podcast-aus-berlin/id1092957894?mt=2), both more newsy, or [`Aufwachen`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/aufwachen/id984970706?mt=2), even though their episodes are eternal. [`A Little Something`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/a-little-something-ein-podcast-%C3%BCber-musik/id1208568135?mt=2) is a good podcast where two journalists discuss music and [`FAZ Einspruch`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/faz-einspruch/id1315944194?mt=2) discusses what is going on in German law at the moment. However, what you are looking for has proven pretty hard for me to find in German as well. I've been craving for a German version of the Political Gabfest or Slate Money. Up until now I have not come across any podcast in German that has even close to the quality of their conversations. (Sorry, I'm new to stack exchange and wasn't able to post more than 8 links, wherefore I had to delete the ones for the Political Gabfest and Slate Money).

Answer (score 1):

Die ct hat einen wöchentlichen Podcast, den [**c't uplink**](http://www.heise.de/ct/blog-ct-uplink-2176079.html).

Seit Anfang des Jahres stellen 4 Redakteure aus dem Heise-Zeitschriftenverlag in wechselnder Besetzung ausgesuchte aktuelle Themen vor und besprechen diese. Die Website heise.de ist in etwa vergleichbar mit Slashdot.

Comment: The format and setting somehow rembered me of earlier *Tekzilla* episodes (I haven't watched it since 2011), but without  scripting, cuts or loud announcement phrases. In german I would say: *gemäßigt*. On second thought *CrankyGeeks* also comes to my mind but more temperate with nobody trying hard to convince the others. Some shows of the *This Week in Tech* network also come to my mind, but these are usually interview style. I'm not sure how well c't uplink can be consumed as an audio only podcast, but the TWiT netcasts mostly work without video.

Comment: Contrary to the US podcasts c't uplink doesn't have commercials or ads currently and it doesn't look like they are trying to include these in the future. I think they are trying to convert only online readers into subscibers of one of their magazines. See also [this post](https://plus.google.com/+ThorstenLeemhuis/posts/2RnFS8fxcSC) from their Open Source and Linux writers for perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you meant when you said you couldn't find anything on iTunes. There is a by-country chart there and you can search through the top podcasts currently trending in Germany. It's also available here: http://www.itunescharts.net/ger/charts/podcasts/ for people who don't have iOS.