# Language-themed podcasts

Tags: resource, big-list

A while ago, I have received recommendations [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17666/podcasts-in-colloquial-german/17956) for non-news podcast in colloquial German. I am also looking for language-themed podcasts, focusing on vocabulary, grammar, and style *for the German-speaking public* (i.e., not for DaF learners).

**Background**: The success of books like *Eats, Shoots and Leaves* marks a resurgence of interests among English speakers in linguistics, language, and style. There are quite a few English podcasts on these subjects. The most well-known probably are [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/grammar-girl), [Lexicon Valley](http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley.html), and [A Way with Words](http://feeds.waywordradio.org/awwwpodcast). I know that Zwiebelfisch has enjoyed great popularity and came out with *Der Dative ist dem Genitive sein Tod*. I was wondering if there are any language-themed podcasts along the same lines.

Comment: As someone who regularly listens to the entertaining *Lexicon Valley* and the excruciatingly boring *The History of English*, I second this question.

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40422/podcasts-about-the-german-language, which despite being asked later seems to have more answers.

Comment: @Close voters: the mentioned duplicate is younger than this question. I think, the younger question should be closed as duplicate and **not** the older original.

Answer (score 3):

One podcast I listen to is "[Neusprechfunk](https://itunes.apple.com/de/podcast/neusprech.org/id545190421?mt=2)". Its topics are similar to the [neusprech.org](http://neusprech.org) blog: how language is used in politics to disguise and mislead ("Neusprech" is the German translation of "newspeak" as it was coined by Orwell).

Answer (score 2):

Various short podcasts (currently 127 episodes, about 3–4 minutes each) on selected topics related to the German language can be found on the website of [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/digitales/podcast).

Answer (score 0):

Longer podcasts or videocasts can be found at [belleslettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/).