# Podcasts about the German language

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, history, spoken-language

I'm searching for podcasts that are about the German language, discussing etymology, language history and the like. Preferably in German but other languages are also of interest.

I've tried searching but I only find podcasts aimed at teaching you German. What I'm searching for are shows that are either similar to the English podcasts

[Lexicon Valley](http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley.html), [A Way with Words](https://www.waywordradio.org/) or [Words for Granted](http://www.wordsforgranted.com/)

or the Swedish radio show/podcast

[Språket i P1](http://sverigesradio.se/spraket)

I'm sure one or more such show exists for German but my Google skills are apparently lacking.

Also if there are any podcasts similar to

[History of English Podcast](http://historyofenglishpodcast.com/)

those would be very interesting as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is podcast about etymology and the usage of German in general from a bavarian radio station called ['Sozusagen! Bemerkungen zur deutschen Sprache'](https://www.br.de/radio/bayern2/sendungen/sozusagen/index.html)
and a Podcast for learners that explains German proverbs called ['Das sagt man so!'](http://www.dw.com/de/deutsch-lernen/das-sagt-man-so/s-32376)

I don't know about any history podcasts though...

Answer (score 5):

This one is in German and discusses various topics, and has some focus on history and etymology.

> http://www.belleslettres.eu/
>
> „Belles Lettres ist ein Videopod­cast für deutsche Sprache, Sprach­kunde und Sti­li­stik. Er wird seit Januar 2010 von Daniel Scholten heraus­gegeben."

Answer (score 1):

I know of one Youtube channel of a German young lady explaining in English issues of German language (and culture) in a quite amusing way. It is called

> Don't trust the rabbit

You will find this by using Search on Youtube.

Yes, it is video, not podcast, but actually the clips are fine just to listen to.